# Why does using "mgcv::s" in "gam(y ~ mgcv::s...)" result in an error?

Tags: r, syntax, mgcv

I wanted to be clear and use the `::` notation in the lines for fitting an `mgcv::gam`. I stumbled over one thing when using the notation within the model call for `mgcv::s`. The code with a reproducible example / error is shown below.

The reason is probably because I am using this notation within the model formula, but I could not figure out why this does not work / is not allowed. This is probably something quite specific concerning syntax (probably not mgcv specific, I guess), but maybe somebody can help me in understanding this and my understanding of R. Thank you in advance.

```
library(mgcv)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 101:110)
# this results in an error: invalid type (list)...
mgcv::gam(y ~ mgcv::s(x, bs = "cs", k = -1), data = dat)
# after removing the mgcv:: in front of s everything works fine
mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", k = -1), data = dat)

# outside of the model call, both calls return the desired function
class(s)
# [1] "function"
class(mgcv::s)
# [1] "function"
```

Comment: this is a good question, but it's kind of a case of "doctor, it hurts when I do this." "well, then don't do that." I appreciate the desire for clarity, but if you were thinking of using `s()` for anything other than a smooth term in a `gam()` formula, that would be pretty crazy ...

Comment: You are right. I am just starting to learn this kind of modelling and was not sure if there might be any function called `s` in other modellng packages and, therefore, wanted to be clear. I guess that as soon as `gam`from mcgv is called, the call would probably parse everything within the model call intepreted as syntax from `mcgv`. So the `mgcv::` in front of `s` is not necessary. Still, using this notation should not result in an error to be consistent with the general notation. But since I know I should not use this notation in this specific case I will follow the doctor`s advice ;-).

Comment: Think of the formula as a symbolic representation of the model, not R code. Whilst you are right that any `s()` lurking ahead of `mgcv:s` on the search path will interfere, manipulating formulas is one of the very hard things you can attempt to do with R.

Comment: @GavinSimpson As you said below, the issue I pointed out is very specific and time can be spent much better than dealing with this one. Nevertheless, I have learned several things about R here, so thank you for your explanations and time spent on this minor issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Explanation**

```
library(mgcv)
#Loading required package: nlme
#This is mgcv 1.8-24. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.

f1 <- ~ s(x, bs = 'cr', k = -1)
f2 <- ~ mgcv::s(x, bs = 'cr', k = -1)

OK <- mgcv:::interpret.gam0(f1)$smooth.spec
FAIL <- mgcv:::interpret.gam0(f2)$smooth.spec

str(OK)
# $ :List of 10
#  ..$ term   : chr "x"
#  ..$ bs.dim : num -1
#  ..$ fixed  : logi FALSE
#  ..$ dim    : int 1
#  ..$ p.order: logi NA
#  ..$ by     : chr "NA"
#  ..$ label  : chr "s(x)"
#  ..$ xt     : NULL
#  ..$ id     : NULL
#  ..$ sp     : NULL
#  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "cr.smooth.spec"

str(FAIL)
# list()
```

The 4th line of the source code of `interpret.gam0` reveals the issue:

```
head(mgcv:::interpret.gam0)

1 function (gf, textra = NULL, extra.special = NULL)              
2 {                                                               
3     p.env <- environment(gf)                                    
4     tf <- terms.formula(gf, specials = c("s", "te", "ti", "t2", 
5         extra.special))                                         
6     terms <- attr(tf, "term.labels")
```

Since `"mgcv::s"` is not to be matched, you get the problem. But `mgcv` does allow you the room to work around this, by passing `"mgcv::s"` via argument `extra.special`:

```
FIX <- mgcv:::interpret.gam0(f, extra.special = "mgcv::s")$smooth.spec
all.equal(FIX, OK)
# [1] TRUE
```

It is just that this is not user-controllable at high-level routine:

```
head(mgcv::gam, n = 10)

#1  function (formula, family = gaussian(), data = list(), weights = NULL, 
#2      subset = NULL, na.action, offset = NULL, method = "GCV.Cp",        
#3      optimizer = c("outer", "newton"), control = list(), scale = 0,     
#4      select = FALSE, knots = NULL, sp = NULL, min.sp = NULL, H = NULL,  
#5      gamma = 1, fit = TRUE, paraPen = NULL, G = NULL, in.out = NULL,    
#6      drop.unused.levels = TRUE, drop.intercept = NULL, ...)             
#7  {                                                                      
#8      control <- do.call("gam.control", control)                         
#9      if (is.null(G)) {                                                  
#10         gp <- interpret.gam(formula)  ## <- default to extra.special = NULL
```

I agree with Ben Bolker. It is a good exercise to dig out what happens inside, but is an over-reaction to consider this as a bug and fix it.

---

**More insight:**

`s`, `te`, etc. in `mgcv` does not work in the same logic with `stats::poly` and `splines::bs`.

- When you do for example, `X <- splines::bs(x, df = 10, degree = 3)`, it **evaluates** `x` and create a design matrix `X` directly.
- When you do `s(x, bs = 'cr', k = 10)`, no evaluation is made; it is **parsed**.

Smooth construction in `mgcv` takes several stages:

1. parsing / interpretation by `mgcv::interpret.gam`, which generates a profile for a smoother;
2. initial construction by `mgcv::smooth.construct`, which sets up basis / design matrix and penalty matrix (mostly done at C-level);
3. secondary construction by `mgcv::smoothCon`, which picks up "by" variable (duplicating smooth for factor "by", for example), linear functional terms, null space penalty (if you use `select = TRUE`), penalty rescaling, centering constraint, etc;
4. final integration by `mgcv:::gam.setup`, which combines all smoothers together, returning a model matrix, etc.

So, it is a far more complicated process.

Comment: thank you for this detailed explanation and insights into the processing steps in mgcv. i agree that this is nothing that has to be fixed. still it is not fully consistent with the typical use of ::

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an `mgcv` issue.  For example, the `lm()` function accepts `poly()` or `stats::poly()` and gives the same results (other than the names of things):

```
> x <- 1:100
> y <- rnorm(100)
> lm(y ~ poly(x, 3))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 3))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  poly(x, 3)1  poly(x, 3)2  poly(x, 3)3  
    0.07074      0.13631     -1.52845     -0.93285  

> lm(y ~ stats::poly(x, 3))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ stats::poly(x, 3))

Coefficients:
       (Intercept)  stats::poly(x, 3)1  stats::poly(x, 3)2  stats::poly(x, 3)3  
           0.07074             0.13631            -1.52845            -0.93285
```

It also works with the `splines::bs` function, so this isn't specific to `poly()`.

You should contact the `mgcv` maintainer and point out this bug in that package.  I'd guess it is looking specifically for `s`, rather than for an expression like `mgcv::s` that evaluates to the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for cross checking and your example with `lm`. At least, it seems that I do no have to update my understanding of using `::`. I will report this issue as suggested.

Comment: I think this works (your two examples) because `poly()` and `bs()` simply return the basis expansion as a matrix of basis functions. So the formula parsing can just evaluate the RHS of the formula in the model frame and you get back something sensible. `s()` does a lot more than than just return a matrix of basis functions evaluated at `x`, so there is a lot more going on in processing a gam formula than what is happening with the `lm` cases you mention.

Comment: What is a bug, or at least an infelicity, in the implementation is that any `s()` defined in your global environment will interfere in the parsing of the formula. Ideally, `gam()` would only ever use it's `s()` when evaluating the smooths. I suspect, however, that in this formula parsing stuff there be dragons and it might just be better to leave things be than try to make this robust to such issues?

Comment: I think a global variable named `s` (created for example by `s <- poly`) should just work (and in my example should act the same as `poly` would).  That's not interference, that's a user overriding the definition of `s`.  `gam()` should not make up its own rules for finding variables, it should use standard rules.

Comment: well, it is - those rules may not be what we might expect (i.e. we want it to use it's own `s()` not something else). That is different from parsing the formula - as I mentioned, and if you look, `lm` works by evaluating the rhs in the environment of the model frame. I don't think this is possible with `mgcv::s()` because it doesn't return anything that fits into R's vision of an evaluate formula. mgcv subsequently creates the correct model matrix, but *it* has to do this; your examples are apples compared with `mgcv::s`'s oranges.

Comment: I haven't dug into the code, but what appears to happen is this:  `gam` looks through the formula for the name `s`, and handles it specially, by substituting something else, then calling the function `s()` on the result.  This fails if it finds a different function named `s()` (as you mentioned), or if the function is specified in a different way (as the original question mentioned). It would be better if it did two things differently:  1, use standard R semantics to find the function if it has a function call in the formula, and 2, look at the function to see if it needs the special handling.