# Non-standard evaluation with mgcv::gam

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I am making a function which takes unevaluated calls to regression functions as input, creates some data, and then evaluates the call. Here is an example:

```
library(lme4)
compute_fit <- function(m){
  # Generate some data
  df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100) + x, ID = sample(4, 100, replace = TRUE))
  # Evaluate the call
  eval(m, envir = df)
}

# Create a list of models
models <- list(
  lm = call("lm", quote(list(formula = y ~ x))),
  glm = call("glm", quote(list(formula = y ~ x))),
  lmer = call("lmer", quote(list(formula = y ~ x + (1 | ID))))
)

# Evaluate the call (this works fine)
model_fits <- lapply(models, compute_fit)
```

My reason for doing this, is that I am conducting a simulation study, where I fit many different models on many Monte Carlo samples. The function is part of an internal package, and I want to provide the list of models, which are then evaluated inside the package.

I would like to also use the `gam` function from `mgcv`. In the documentation to gam, the following is said about its `data` argument, which is practically equivalent to, e.g., the documentation to `lm`:

> A data frame or list containing the model response variable and covariates required by the formula. By default the variables are taken from environment(formula): typically the environment from which gam is called.

I hence try to use the same logic to compute a `gam`, thinking that `eval(m, envir = df)` in the `compute_fit` function defined above should evaluate the formula in the environment of `df`:

```
# Try with gam
library(mgcv)
gamcall = call("gam", quote(list(formula = y ~ x)))    
compute_fit(gamcall)
```

However, this fails with the error message:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env): object 'y' not found

I realize that this error is likely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051732/why-does-using-mgcvs-in-gamy-mgcvs-result-in-an-error), however my question is whether anyone can think of a workaround which lets me use `gam` in the same way as I use the other modeling functions? To the best of my understanding, the linked question does not provide a solution to this question.

Here is a complete reprex:

```r
set.seed(1)
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
compute_fit <- function(m){
  # Generate some data
  df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), ID = rep(1:50, 2))
  df$y <- df$x + rnorm(100, sd = .1)
  # Evaluate the call
  eval(m, envir = df)
}

# Create a list of models
models <- list(
  lm = call("lm", quote(list(formula = y ~ x))),
  glm = call("glm", quote(list(formula = y ~ x))),
  lmer = call("lmer", quote(list(formula = y ~ x + (1 | ID))))
)

# Evaluate the call (this works fine)
model_fits <- lapply(models, compute_fit)

# Try with gam
library(mgcv)
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'nlme'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:lme4':
#> 
#>     lmList
#> This is mgcv 1.8-26. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.
gamcall = call("gam", quote(list(formula = y ~ x)))    
compute_fit(gamcall)    
#> Error in eval(predvars, data, env): object 'y' not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add `df` to the call instead of evaluating within `df`:

```
compute_fit <- function(m){
  # Generate some data
  set.seed(1)
  df <- data.frame(x <- rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100) + x^3, ID = sample(4, 100, replace = TRUE))
  #add data parameter to call
  m[["data"]] <- quote(df)
  # Evaluate the call
  eval(m)
}

# Create a list of models
models <- list(
  lm = quote(lm(formula = y ~ x)),
  glm = quote(glm(formula = y ~ x)),
  lmer = quote(lmer(formula = y ~ x + (1 | ID))),
  gam = quote(gam(formula = y ~ s(x)))
)

model_fits <- lapply(models, compute_fit)
#works but lmer reports singular fit
```